# Pictures and videos not showing in the gallery

Tags: photos, video, gallery

I've been experiencing this issue for a month or so. I was using the camera and I received a message of some memory error, but was able to continue taking pictures. Then I realized that the pictures were not showing up in the gallery.

I connected the device to my PC and the files are actually there. In addition, I am able to continue taking pictures and access the files when using the camera (I touch the recent photos icon and I can see them).

I have tried many things, such as removing the DCIM folder, erasing the `.nomedia` files, and erasing data from the internal memory, and none of them seemed to work.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Have you tried triggering the Media Scanner manually? There are many apps in the playstore helping you doing so, e.g. [SDRescan](http://www.appbrain.com/app/sdrescan/com.bero.sdrescan), [Rescan SD](http://www.appbrain.com/app/rescan-sd-card/com.uberullu.rescansd), or [Media Library Repair Scanner](http://www.appbrain.com/app/media-library-repair-scanner/com.azend.refreshmusic).

Answer (score 9):

Consider any of the solution mentioned below.

#### Solution 1

Note: Follow the steps for both Internal and external SD Card

1. Go to File manager  -> Android ->  Data -> `com.android.gallery3d`.
2. Delete the folder (`com.android.gallery3d`) in both internal and external SD card.
3. Go to Settings -> Apps / Application manager -> search for Gallery -> open Gallery and tap on Clear Data .
4. Switch off your phone and wait for few minutes (say 2-3 min) and then switch on and wait for few minutes.

That's it now. All the images and videos would be showing under Gallery.

#### Solution 2

1. Go to the respective folders where images/videos are stored.
2. Go to Settings > Show hidden file and see if there is  a `.NOMEDIA` file. If there is such file then delete it.
3. Switch off and switch on the device.

That's it.

#### Solution 3

If above solutions don't work, then you have to search for apps in Play Store which scans SD Card . SDrescan is good. It's only of 20KB in size. And then scan the memory card using that app.

Answer (score 2):

Workaround: In my case, the images with a very long name didn't show up in the Gallery. After I renamed them, they showed up.

---

Update: A rename by adding one more character (in the Total Commander
/ X-plore app that can see them) triggered the display in Gallery (or other Apps like Google Photos, WhatsApp, and Telegram that can share images), so it is not about the name length. The owner didn't change, the timestamp didn't change either.

The root cause remains to be discovered.

Comment: same thing happening to me. All the videos I download are in SD Card / Download. But I have to rename them (even add or remove 1 letter) from file manager. It starts showing them in gallery.

Comment: This happens because the downloaded image isn't indexed right way. The indexing tool works based on some triggers - like renaming an existing file, deleting some files etc and this is why it starts showing up after you rename it.
Source - https://forums.androidcentral.com/showthread.php?t=640672&p=4985918&viewfull=1#post4985918

Answer (score 1):

The solution to your problem requires two steps:

1. You have to delete `.nomedia` file by connecting your phone to a computer. Once you are done with that, come back to your phone.
2. Go to storage in Settings and do 'UnMount SD Card'. Wait for a few seconds and do 'Mount SD Card', and that's it.

All your photos and videos will now be listed in the Gallery and respective apps.

Answer (score 0):

As of September 28, 2023, I had this exact problem, so I started doing some research and nothing worked.  I remembered that I was messing up with my phone earlier and changed some settings, so I went back there and figured out what was causing this problem.

In order to fix this. Follow the steps on the screenshots I'm going to attach.

1. First go to Settings ⚙️
2. Scroll down to Apps
3. Top-right corner, you will find 3 vertical dots that look like this ⫶

   [image]
4. Select Special Access
5. Select Usage Data Access
6. Click the 3 vertical dots ⫶ on the top right corner again
7. Then click Reset App Preferences

   [image]
8. ✔️ Done.

*Just so you know, the phone will tell you. You will not lose any data by performing this.* But you might have to sign in to apps again like Uber or apps that require sign-in.

Answer (score -2):

First, go to File manager > Settings > Show hidden files > then rename the folder `.nomedia` to `.adc`. Then restart your phone and remove the SD card directly without unmounting. Then reinsert it to the phone during switch on and watch. By default, it will scan the SD card and show media in the gallery and music.

If it does not work, then delete the folder `.nomedia` and do the step of removing and inserting the SD card again, then open the gallery.

Comment: 1) `.nomedia` usually is a file, not a folder 2) OP already stated those files *removed* 3) removing the card without unmount from a running system is strongly discouraged, as it might lead to data loss.