# Image not display in Gallery

Tags: screen, images

What is the reason and solution to display images in SD card but not display in Gallery in Android Phone ?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please [edit] your question and include at least: The device you're using, Android version it is running and more details on exactly what the problem you're having is. Also check and update the tags you've used to match your issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pictures and videos not showing in the gallery](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/55967/pictures-and-videos-not-showing-in-the-gallery)

Comment: Also see [How do I make older images in my /sdcard/DCIM folder show up in Gallery?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/25676)